# Generating text using LSTM given condition vector

Tags: neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, generative-models

I know that you can use an RNN to generate text given the first few letters

```
ex) "The ca" => (passed into RNN) => "The cat is walking down the street."
```

I would like to know if you can generate text by passing in a condition

```
ex) condition = "ocean"
    embed condition into some distributed vector => [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
    pass embedded condition vector into LSTM to generate text => "The fish are swimming away."
```

Would something like this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options, the most popular ones being:

- Transform the conditionning vector to obtain the first hidden state and/or cell state.
- Concatenate the conditionning vector to each input vector, cf. Lipton & al. 2016

References:

- [Capturing meaning in product reviews with character-level generative text models, Lipton & al. 2016](http://zacklipton.com/media/papers/capturing-meaning-product_lipton2015.pdf)